# Adding references in monodevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

In simply words i cant add reference in mono project the button "edit reference" in project menu is not active, i tryied to make new project and paste my code but button was still not active? How coudl i add reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably got it already, still if anyone else comes across it- you need to make sure you select the project (to which you wish to add references) in the solution view and then add references (by either going to Project then Edit references or right clicking on the project); as long as the solution is selected in this view the edit references menu item will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit references(you can get this by right clicking on the reference icon). If you would like to add a package, you can do that by selecting the  require package under the package tab.But, if you would like to add the reference from a local project library, go to the .Net Assembly tab and browse for the location of the .dll file (most often it will be in the bin folder of that local library project), and add it to your project.